# PowerPivot: Join tables with multiple data

Tags: powerquery, powerpivot

I dont know if it is possible, but i have **3 tables in PowerPivot**:

each table reflects the history of one worker per store and per department and per function.

```
User    Store   DateChangeStore
User 1  Store 1 01/01/2019
User 1  Store 2 01/05/2019

User    Dept    DateChangeDpt
User 1  Dept 1  01/01/2019
User 1  Dept 2  01/03/2019
User 1  Dept 1  01/06/2019

User    Function DateChangeFct
User 1  Func 1   01/01/2019
User 1  Func 2   01/02/2019
```

And i want to transform into one table like this below, but the twist is that I want to relate with the date.

> Per example:

user 1 when entered we was on store 1, department 1 with function 1.
But when he changed to function 2, he was still on store 1 and department 1...

**Is possible to see by the change date.**

```
User    Store   DateChangeStore Dept    DateChangeDpt   Function    DateChangeFct
User 1  Store 1 01/01/2019      Dept 1  01/01/2019      Func 1     01/01/2019
User 1  Store 1 01/01/2019      Dept 1  01/01/2019      Func 2     01/02/2019
User 1  Store 1 01/01/2019      Dept 2  01/03/2019      Func 2     01/02/2019
User 1  Store 2 01/05/2019      Dept 2  01/03/2019      Func 2     01/02/2019
User 1  Store 2 01/05/2019      Dept 1  01/06/2019      Func 2     01/02/2019
```

**Is this possible in any way?**

thank you

**-- UPDATE --**

i Only gave an example with 1 user, but the original data as multiple users:

example below

```html
User    Store   DateChangeStore
User 1  Store 1 01/01/2019
User 1  Store 2 01/05/2019
User 2 Store 1 01/06/2019

User    Dept    DateChangeDpt
User 1  Dept 1  01/01/2019
User 1  Dept 2  01/03/2019
User 1  Dept 3  01/06/2019
User 2  Dept 1 01/06/2019
User 2 Dept 2 01/07/2019

User    Function DateChangeFct
User 1  Func 1   01/01/2019
User 1  Func 2   01/02/2019
User 2 Func 1 01/06/2019
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initial attempt at a solution in Power Query might be something like:

```
let
    storeTable = Table.FromColumns({{"User 1", "User 1"}, {"Store 1", "Store 2"}, {#date(2019, 1, 1), #date(2019, 5, 1)}}, {"User", "Store", "DateChangeStore"}),
    deptTable = Table.FromColumns({{"User 1", "User 1", "User 1"}, {"Dept 1", "Dept 2", "Dept 3"}, {#date(2019, 1, 1), #date(2019, 3, 1), #date(2019,6,1)}}, {"User", "Dept", "DateChangeDept"}),
    funcTable = Table.FromColumns({{"User 1", "User 1"}, {"Func 1", "Func 2"}, {#date(2019, 1, 1), #date(2019, 2, 1)}}, {"User", "Function", "DateChangeFct"}),
    distinctDates = List.Distinct(storeTable[DateChangeStore] & deptTable[DateChangeDept] & funcTable[DateChangeFct]),
    columnOfDates = Table.FromColumns({distinctDates}, type table [changeDate = date]),
    joinedStore = Table.NestedJoin(columnOfDates, {"changeDate"}, storeTable, {"DateChangeStore"}, "toExpand", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    expandedStore = Table.ExpandTableColumn(joinedStore, "toExpand", {"User", "Store", "DateChangeStore"}, {"User", "Store", "DateChangeStore"}),
    joinedDept = Table.NestedJoin(expandedStore, {"changeDate"}, deptTable, {"DateChangeDept"}, "toExpand", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    expandedDept = Table.ExpandTableColumn(joinedDept, "toExpand", {"DateChangeDept"}),
    joinedFunction = Table.NestedJoin(expandedDept, {"changeDate"}, funcTable, {"DateChangeFct"}, "toExpand", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    expandedFunction = Table.ExpandTableColumn(joinedFunction, "toExpand", {"DateChangeFct"}),
    sorted = Table.Sort(expandedFunction,{{"changeDate", Order.Ascending}}),
    filledDown = Table.FillDown(sorted,{"User", "Store", "DateChangeStore", "DateChangeDept", "DateChangeFct"})
in
    filledDown
```

which gives me the following:

[image: Output table]

which appears to match the example you've given in your question (as far as I can see). (Also, try testing with some different data to see if output is still correct and as expected.)

If everything's okay with output, code can be refined (to avoid repetition) into something like:

```
let
    // You don't need the lines below (I only use them to generate the data in the example). You should replace them with your own tables/code.
    storeTable = Table.FromColumns({{"User 1", "User 1"}, {"Store 1", "Store 2"}, {#date(2019, 1, 1), #date(2019, 5, 1)}}, {"User", "Store", "DateChangeStore"}),
    deptTable = Table.FromColumns({{"User 1", "User 1", "User 1"}, {"Dept 1", "Dept 2", "Dept 3"}, {#date(2019, 1, 1), #date(2019, 3, 1), #date(2019,6,1)}}, {"User", "Dept", "DateChangeDept"}),
    funcTable = Table.FromColumns({{"User 1", "User 1"}, {"Func 1", "Func 2"}, {#date(2019, 1, 1), #date(2019, 2, 1)}}, {"User", "Function", "DateChangeFct"}),

    columnOfDates = 
        let
            allDates = storeTable[DateChangeStore] & deptTable[DateChangeDept] & funcTable[DateChangeFct],
            deduplicated = List.Distinct(allDates),
            asTable = Table.FromColumns({deduplicated}, type table [changeDate = date])
        in asTable,
    LeftJoinAndExpand = (leftTable as table, leftJoinColumn as text, rightTable, rightJoinColumn, expandAllInRightTable as logical) =>
        let
            joined = Table.NestedJoin(leftTable, {leftJoinColumn}, rightTable, {rightJoinColumn}, "$toExpand", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
            columnsToExpand = if expandAllInRightTable then Table.ColumnNames(rightTable) else {rightJoinColumn},
            expanded = Table.ExpandTableColumn(joined, "$toExpand", columnsToExpand)
        in expanded,
    joinedStore = LeftJoinAndExpand(columnOfDates, "changeDate", storeTable, "DateChangeStore", true),
    joinedDept = LeftJoinAndExpand(joinedStore, "changeDate", deptTable, "DateChangeDept", false),
    joinedFunc = LeftJoinAndExpand(joinedDept, "changeDate", funcTable, "DateChangeFct", false),
    sorted = Table.Sort(joinedFunc, {{"changeDate", Order.Ascending}}),
    filledDown = Table.FillDown(sorted, {"User", "Store", "DateChangeStore", "DateChangeDept", "DateChangeFct"})
in
    filledDown
```

**And for multiple users:**

You could try something like:

```
let
    storeTable = Table.FromColumns({{"User 1", "User 1", "User 2"}, {"Store 1", "Store 2", "Store 1"}, {#date(2019, 1, 1), #date(2019, 5, 1), #date(2019, 6, 1)}}, type table [User = text, Store = text, DateChangeStore = date]),
    deptTable = Table.FromColumns({{"User 1", "User 1", "User 1", "User 2", "User 2"}, {"Dept 1", "Dept 2", "Dept 3", "Dept 1", "Dept 2"}, {#date(2019, 1, 1), #date(2019, 3, 1), #date(2019, 6, 1), #date(2019, 6, 1), #date(2019, 7, 1)}}, type table [User = text, Dept = text, DateChangeDept = date]),
    funcTable = Table.FromColumns({{"User 1", "User 1", "User 2"}, {"Func 1", "Func 2", "Func 1"}, {#date(2019, 1, 1), #date(2019, 2, 1), #date(2019, 6, 1)}}, type table [User = text, Function = text, DateChangeFct = date]),
    // You don't need the lines above (I only use them to generate the data in the example).
    // You should replace them with your own tables/code.

    renamePairs = {{"DateChangeStore", "$changeDate"}, {"DateChangeDept", "$changeDate"}, {"DateChangeFct", "$changeDate"}},
    toCombine = List.Transform({storeTable, deptTable, funcTable}, each Table.SelectColumns(Table.RenameColumns(_, renamePairs, MissingField.Ignore), {"User", "$changeDate"})),
    combined = Table.Distinct(Table.Combine(toCombine), {"User", "$changeDate"}),
    LeftJoinAndExpand = (leftTable as table, leftJoinKeys as list, rightTable as table, rightJoinKeys as list) as table =>
        let
            joined = Table.NestedJoin(leftTable, leftJoinKeys, rightTable, rightJoinKeys, "$toExpand", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
            columnsToExpand = List.Difference(Table.ColumnNames(rightTable), Table.ColumnNames(leftTable)),
            expanded = Table.ExpandTableColumn(joined, "$toExpand", columnsToExpand)
        in expanded,
    groupedAndJoined = Table.Group(combined, {"User"}, {"$toExpand", (userTable) => 
            let
                joinedStore = LeftJoinAndExpand(userTable, {"User", "$changeDate"}, storeTable, {"User", "DateChangeStore"}),
                joinedDept = LeftJoinAndExpand(joinedStore, {"User", "$changeDate"}, deptTable, {"User", "DateChangeDept"}),
                joinedFunc = LeftJoinAndExpand(joinedDept, {"User", "$changeDate"}, funcTable, {"User", "DateChangeFct"})
            in joinedFunc
        , type table}),

    // Am doing this as a separate step (rather than in previous step) only so that the JOIN results can be previewed in Query Editor.
    fillDownNestedTables = Table.TransformColumns(groupedAndJoined, {"$toExpand", (userTable) => 
            let
                sorted = Table.Sort(userTable, {{"User", Order.Ascending}, {"$changeDate", Order.Ascending}}),
                columnsToFill = List.RemoveMatchingItems(Table.ColumnNames(sorted), {"User", "$changeDate"}),
                filledDown = Table.FillDown(sorted, columnsToFill),
                dropHelperColumn = Table.RemoveColumns(filledDown, {"$changeDate"})
            in dropHelperColumn 
        , type table}),
    expandNestedTables = 
        let
            allHeaders = List.Combine(List.Transform(Table.Column(fillDownNestedTables, "$toExpand"), Table.ColumnNames)),
            columnsToExpand = List.Difference(List.Distinct(allHeaders), Table.ColumnNames(fillDownNestedTables)),
            expanded = Table.ExpandTableColumn(fillDownNestedTables, "$toExpand", columnsToExpand)
        in expanded 
in
    expandNestedTables
```

which gives me:

[image: Multiple users output]

which I think is correct (but I'm not sure if the logic/transformation/approach is as efficient as it could be).

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Just have 2 question, just to understand the code: 1. what does the "changeDate"? 2. What does "toExpand" on the first code? Thank you again, was this that i was looking for :)

Comment: @VanessaGoncalves, #1 the `changeDate` column contains the unique dates across all three tables. This `changeDate` column itself is used as the left join key during the join operation. It is needed during the transformation, but you can get rid of it once the transformation is complete (i.e after `filledDown` step/expression). #2 `"toExpand"` in the first bit of code (and `"$toExpand"` in the second bit of code) is the name/header of the column containing the results of the join operation. My understanding is that join operations in...

Comment: ...Power Query occur in two steps. First you "join" (and get a column containing tables/the results of the join operation). Then you "expand" the results/tables so that they become new columns in the table. This "expansion" step is why I called the column `toExpand`, but you could give it any name (that doesn't already exist in your table).

Comment: work its been crazy, and just was possible now to convert this to my real data. And realized that this code isnt total working, because, only works if i just have 1 user. They can only be joint my the date, as to be by the user too. Can you help me with that? thank you :)

Comment: @VanessaGoncalves The example in your question only contained 1 user, hence why the answer only works for 1 user. To make the code work with multiple users, I would think a `Table.Group` (with `User` column as group key) would need to be added -- and then invoke the existing code within each "group". But to be sure that I understand the problem correctly, if you provide some example data (containing multiple users) as well as the output you expect, then I'll take a look.

Comment: Hmm, i edited the post with an update with an example with 2 users. Thank you for the help :). Im trying to solve it, but im really newby so i think im going the complicated route

Comment: user 2 should only appear 2 times in the table, but is appearing 3. User 2 dont have dept 3 associated... Its seems that is because of the dept date...

Comment: I think i resolve it, i added the "user", along with the "$changedate", as a LeftjoinKey and rightJoinkey. :)

Comment: Okay, sounds like you've got it, but I've edited my post anyway.